What is the method to remember a "1 to many" relationship database change history?
I have basically two tables in the database, one is named "Valve", and the other is named "Channel". This is a basic "1 to many" relationship, which means one Valve can control many Channels. See the image below:

In this figure, you see four sub-figures. The first sub-figure (day0), it shows that Valve0(V0) is controlling 3 Channels(C0, C1 and C2), Valve1(V1) is controlling the Channel3(C3).
This is a very basic "1 to many" relationship, so I create two tables, one is named "ValveTable", and the other is named "ChannelTable". In the "ChannelTable", it has a foreign key named "ValveID" which points to the primary key of the "ValveTable".
But in my cases, the tree structure will change day by day. In the day1, the property of the C0 will changes, so do I need to make a new copy of C0 row in the "ChannelTable"? Because I need to remember the day0's tree hierarchy. Also, the C2 is connected to V1 in day1, so the connection is changed.
In the day2, C1 is removed from V0. And in day3, a new Channel C4 is added to the ChannelTable, so it got the new tree hierarchy.
I'm not sure how to design this whole database structure. Do I need to add a third table? just like a Conneciton Table or something like a "junction table" like a "many to many" relationship database?
Any good ideas? The whole picture is very large, and this is a very simplified question, the core issue is that I need to keep the tree structure change history in the database.
Thanks.
EDIT:
Julio Di Egidio's answer give me an example of the "ChannelsPerDay" table, where the "DayNo" is a FK. But in-fact, in my figure, I wrote "day0, day1, day2 and day3" which is a simplification of the situation that the "Valve-Channel" relationship may be changed at some timestamp, for example, one channel may be deleted at the timestamp of "2023-11-24 10:31:21". So, I need find a way to actually use the timestamp as the field, not the "DayNo".


I need to keep the tree structure change history in the database.

Then you need to store "channels per day".
Namely, an immediate solution here is to add a field, say DayNo, to Channels that forms a composite PK with the ID, meaning that every entry in Channels represents uniquely "a channel in some specific day":
Valves {
  ID  PK
}

Channels {
  ID       PK
  DayNo    PK
  ValveID     FK -> Valves.ID
}

One could then think of splitting Channels into Channels (just the list, including the "obsolete" ones), and -say- ChannelsPerDay, for a bit more normalization, but this adds extra complication that I would think is warranted only if Channels has to have more info about a channel than just an ID.
In any case, for completeness, here is the corresponding structure, with Name fields to give the example more substance:
Valves {
  ID  PK
  Name   UK  // assuming we want unique names
}

Channels {
  ID  PK
  Name   UK  // assuming we want unique names
}

ChannelsPerDay {
  ChannelID  PK FK1 -> Channels.ID
  DayNo      PK
  ValveID       FK2 -> Valves.ID
}

Notice in particular that that structure (but also the previous one) does support not recording "non-changes", namely there is no constraint that the table ChannelsPerDay is "complete" in some sense.  Two considerations about that:

should we want to enforce "completeness", as for relational constraints (as opposed to e.g. jobs that send emails...), I don't think we can do better than enforcing completeness table-level at the next insertion, i.e. where a record can be inserted if the data is "complete up to that point";

OTOH, if it's fine to have those gaps (and, typically, I'd go this way), just the semantics changes, namely, it becomes a history of "updates", and we'd rather need adequate queries to reconstruct the "current state" (which of course we can do).


Now, the second approach, a "history of updates", is the one you are interested in.  It further splits into two possibilities, i.e. whether or not it is a requirement that channels can at periods be detached from all valves:

The structure I have given above assumes that a channel is always attached to some valve, there is in fact no way there to say that a channel gets detached from all valves (other than creating a dummy valve to which to attach "detached" channels, which is anyway not ideal). --  I have created a minimal playground, covering your Day0->Day1, up to a sample query to describe this case.

In case the requirement is that a channel can be at periods detached from all valves (as it seems to be in your case, looking at Day2 in the example), the structure has to change slightly: namely, the ValveID field in ChannelsPerDay (the "history" table) must become NULLable.  And the (INNER) JOIN with Valves in the query in the playground can become an OUTER JOIN, depending on the specific output that is wanted. --  I have created another playground, covering from your Day0 to Day3, again up to a sample query to recover the state at some time.



Hi, thanks for the answer. In my question, the "day" is just a simplified field for a general "timestamp", I mean the change of the valve-channel relationship could happens in any time stamp, such as that: one channel is removed at the timestamp 2024-05-01T22-07-01, so how to modify the "ChannelsPerDay" table? Thanks.

Another issue is that in your design, do I need to record every channels for a single day? I mean in my question, the channel "C3" is never modified through all the time, so there is only "one" record in the "ChannelsPerDay" table? Or I need 4 records for the "C3" in this table?

Hi, thanks, I have just read your added words in your answer, I'm not really understand the idea, what does the "completeness" mean? You mean I would like to remember all the history? The idea I need to remember the "valve-channel" structure is that I need to know what is tree structure look like at "which time". So, maybe, a new method is to add a "add_time" and "delete_time" column for both the two tables?

Hi, thanks for the response, I think I have understand the "gaps" and "no gaps". The "gaps" means that you only need to record the changes for some day time. While the "no gaps" means you need to remember every days' settings. For me, I certainly need the "gaps" way. Also, if you have time, can you add the query about how to reconstruct the configuration if I give you a day number. I mean I need to reconstruct the configuration from the "history of the updates" table. Thanks.

Hi, @Julio Di Egidio, thanks for supplying both the "schema SQL" and "query SQL", I can understand the "schema SQL", but the "query SQL" is so complex that it is a bit hard for me to understand. I'm struggling to understand this query statement. I haven't seen such complex query statement before, so I think I will take some time to learn it. What will the query SQL command get? Can you give some result about the query SQL? Thanks.

@ollydbg23  If you don't know SQL, that's altogether another problem, and not one I can resolve here: my answer to the present question is more than complete at this point, you had asked about a "model" (schema).  You will have to ask new and more specific questions if you need help proceeding. -- As for "what will the query get", there is a "RUN" button near the top-left of the playground page...

OK, thanks, I haven't see the "RUN" button, let me try it, and indeed, I need to learn some advanced SQL grammar.
